# How to set a header on a WebSocketPeer?

Tags: websocket, gdscript, godot-4

How to pass custom header information on a Godot4 WebSocketPeer connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I have found how to do this:

1. Create an instance of `PackedStringArray`
2. Add it to the WS Client using `_set_handshake_headers`

Example:

```
var _connHeader = PackedStringArray(["header-key: header-value"])
_mySocket.set_handshake_headers(_connHeader)
```